# iPhone Newsstand push registration Failure

Tags: apple-push-notifications

// Register for notifications

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability)];
```

This is the code I use for registering for registering for push notifications. The app registers for Alert, Badges, Sound. But the app did not register for the newsstand push notifications. Checked it in

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

method, with this condition

```
if([application enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] & UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability)
```

What might the issue with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already include the Newsstand Info.plist keys? You can check if the app registered for Newsstand pushes in Settings/Store.

Comment: yes, all the settings for the app are done. The app was shown in the newsstand also. But the problem is with the registering of the pushnotifications

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications don't work on iPhone Simulator, so try to run it on a device.

If this doesn't help, try to:

- implement
  application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: method
  on delegate and check error description
- check push settings for this app ID and regenerate provisioning profile
- check [aps-environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW5)