# Newsstand App download when app is closed

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, newsstand-kit

I am implementing a newsstand magazine app, which receives new issues via Urban Airship push notifications.
This works fine, as long as the app is in foreground or background, but as far as I know, the download should also be triggered when the app is completely closed. But sending a push with `"content-available":1` in the payload does not do anything if my app is closed.

I set the required background mode in the targets properties and I use `NKDontThrottleNewsstandContentNotifications` to avoid problems with testing.

Am I missing something?

Shouldn't the push lead to my

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

being called with `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey`?

Help much appreciated!

Comment: Are you testing over 3G or WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

As per [this article](http://www.macstories.net/stories/ios-5-newsstand-overview/),

*developers that are developing Newsstand apps can deliver a new “souped-up” push notification that informs their app (rather than the user as push notifications normally do), that a new issue is ready to be downloaded. When a Newsstand app receives such a notification, **it can download in the background if the device is on WiFi**. The main limitation here is that each app can only send 1 of these push notifications per day, so at the moment developers cannot develop newspapers that deliver both a morning edition and evening edition – although I suspect this might change eventually.*

So it can download only if the device is on Wifi.

These are other similar questions, [new stand push and execute code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980910/new-stand-push-and-execute-code), [iOS newsstand: push notification does not launch the app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218073/ios-newsstand-push-notification-does-not-launch-the-app-in-background), [Newsstand restarts the download on Resuming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034880/newsstand-restarts-the-download-on-resuming?rq=1) and this [iPhone Newsstand push registration Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832432/iphone-newsstand-push-registration-failure?rq=1). Check if you are missing anything mentioned in those answers as well.

Here is the [apple documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2280/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011215) and another [blog on this](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Platform_Features/Introduction_to_Newsstand).