# Newsstand Application stop downloading when app is in the background

Tags: ios, ios7, newsstand-kit

In my Newsstand based app, when I'm connected to 3G, if I start downloading, it works. But once I go to background, it stops downloading. Even if I open the app, it doesn't start downloading. If I switch to the Wi-Fi, then the application continues downloading.

Comment: Not a bug, but a feature. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031589/newsstand-app-download-when-app-is-closed

Comment: Yp dat should be happen when a new issue comes through push notifications. In my case when i start the download manually it starts in 3G.But when i go to background it stops. Even i open the app still it doesnt resume in 3G